# Jquery set onclick event without element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a card list.
Before I draw a card, the card list is like this:

```
<div id="cards-div">
    <ul id="cards-list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

After I draw a card, the card list is like this:

```
<div id="cards-div">
    <ul id="cards-list">
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I add an onclick function **receiving the index at the same time**:

```
<div id="cards-div">
    <ul id="cards-list">
        <li onclick="mouseoverCard(index)">hello</li>
    </ul>
</div>

mouseoverCard: function(index) {
    alert(index);
}
```

Please note that I tried declaring mouseover function using jquery.click() but it only works when the DOM exists. I want to declare function even the DOM is not exist.

Comment: Have you looked into "event delegation"?

Comment: use on delegated event... http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html  to read about on delegated event

Answer (score 4):

As I understood, parent `<ul>` element is static. So you may use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$("#cards-list").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    var i = $(this).index();
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the `#cards-list`, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked `li` to `ul`):

```
$("#cards-list").on("click", "li", function(event){
     alert($(this).index());
});
```

Reference: [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)